# Class method breaks after resize event listener

Tags: javascript

Here is a small example of my problem. I am trying to build a responsive class that will adjust my page when I change the width size.

Upon changing the size the method that was originally called disappears. You can test it yourself by adjusting the page size.

```js
class PageManager {
  constructor() {
    this.width;
    this.isMobile;
  }

  init() {
    this.attachListeners();
    this.widthChanges();
    this.adjustPage();
  }

  attachListeners() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.widthChanges);
  }

  widthChanges() {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.adjustPage();
    if (this.width < 491) {
      this.isMobile = true
    } else {
      this.isMobile = false
    }
  }

  adjustPage() {
    console.log("fired");
  }
}

const pageManager = new PageManager();
pageManager.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a scope problem, the function `adjustPage` doesn't exists under the scope of the function `widthChanges`.

When you call `this.adjustPage()` in the function `widthChanges`, `this` will be the context of the function `widthChanges` not the context of the class PageManager, so, the function `ajustPage` doesn't exist.

You can fix your problem binding the class context into the functions, just like bellow.

You can find a little bit more about this and scrope here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
class PageManager {
  constructor() {
    this.width;
    this.isMobile;
    this.attachListeners = this.attachListeners.bind(this);
    this.widthChanges = this.widthChanges.bind(this);
  }

  init() {
    this.attachListeners();
    this.widthChanges();
    this.adjustPage();
  }

  attachListeners() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.widthChanges);
  }

  widthChanges() {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.adjustPage();
    if (this.width < 491) {
      this.isMobile = true
    } else {
      this.isMobile = false
    }
  }

  adjustPage() {
    console.log("fired");
  }
}

const pageManager = new PageManager();
pageManager.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback to addEventListener is called with the object on which the event was added (in this case, the window) bound as `this`. You can either use an arrow function or bind the `this` value yourself.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", this.widthChanges.bind(this));
//or
window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>this.widthChanges());
```